# Google Apps script. How to get cell from the left and navigater ov

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to this. Checked docs, googled, but could not find what I wanted as easy.

With Google Apps Script,

I would like to get a cell object that is close to the left of current one.

```
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    
       var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell()

 // var priceColumn = cell.getColumn()-1;

  // var strategyColumn = cell.getColumn()-2;
```

cell.left?

Basically I would need to navite lef and right, up and down from the curent cell..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [offset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) function:

Examples:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell();

var newCell = cell.offset(0, 1); // cell to the right
var newCell = cell.offset(0, -1); // cell to the left
var newCell = cell.offset(1, 0); // cell below
var newCell = cell.offset(-1, 0); // cell above
```

`offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)` :

[image]